# how to update a table in sqlite corresponding to a id

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i have 2 forms. first form saves value to company_master except 2 fields.In second form want to update company_master in sqlite when id=1 those 2 fileds.

in form2 i have tried simple update but it doesnot work

form1.xaml

```
 private async void OnSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ECompnyPhone.Text))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                if (pickCompnyType.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    type = "Academic";
                }
                else if (pickCompnyType.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    type = "Financial";
                }

                if (pickYear.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    year = "April - March";
                }
                else if (pickYear.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    year = "January - December";
                }

                var cmpny = new COMPANY_MASTER
                {
                    Name = ECompnyName.Text,
                    PhoneNo = ECompnyPhone.Text,
                    Email = ECompnyEmail.Text,
                    Address1 = ECompnyAdd1.Text,
                    Address2 = ECompnyAdd2.Text,
                    Address3 = ECompnyAdd3.Text,
                    Type = type,
                    Wing = EWing.Text,
                    Year = year
                };
                var checker = await _connection.InsertAsync(cmpny);
                if (checker == 1)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Message", "Data saved successfully.", "Ok");
                    await Navigation.PopAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Error in data saving. Please retry later.", "Ok");
        }
    }
```

form2.xaml

```
private async void OnSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var expense = new COMPANY_MASTER
            {

                Opening_Cash = Convert.ToDecimal(EOCash.Text),
                Available_Cash = Convert.ToDecimal(EACash.Text)
            };

           var checker = await _connection.UpdateAsync(expense);
            if (checker == 1)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Message", "Data saved successfully.", "Ok");
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Error in data saving. Please retry later.", "Ok");
        }
    }
```

Company_master.cs

```
 public class COMPANY_MASTER : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string _name { get; set; }
        public string _address1 { get; set; }
        public string _address2 { get; set; }
        public string _address3 { get; set; }
        public string _email { get; set; }
        public string _phoneNo { get; set; }
        public string _type { get; set; }
        public string _wing { get; set; }
        public string _year { get; set; }
        public decimal _openingcash { get; set; }
        public decimal _availablecash { get; set; }

        public decimal Available_Cash
        {
            get { return _availablecash; }
            set
            {
                if (_availablecash == value)

                    return;
                _availablecash = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public decimal Opening_Cash
        {
            get { return _openingcash; }
            set
            {
                if (_openingcash == value)

                    return;
                _openingcash = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (_name == value)

                    return;
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string Year
        {
            get { return _year; }
            set
            {
                if (_year == value)

                    return;
                _year = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Wing
        {
            get { return _wing; }
            set
            {
                if (_wing == value)

                    return;
                _wing = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
         public string Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set
            {
                if (_type == value)

                    return;
                _type = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string PhoneNo
        {
            get { return _phoneNo; }
            set
            {
                if (_phoneNo == value)

                    return;
                _phoneNo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Address1
        {
            get { return _address1; }
            set
            {
                if (_address1 == value)

                    return;
                _address1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Address2
        {
            get { return _address2; }
            set
            {
                if (_address2 == value)

                    return;
                _address2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string Address3
        {
            get { return _address3; }
            set
            {
                if (_address3 == value)

                    return;
                _address3 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Email
        {
            get { return _email; }
            set
            {
                if (_email == value)

                    return;
                _email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

i want to update company_master's opening_cash and available_cash where companyid=1 in form2

now updation is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can't update a new element

```
        var expense = new COMPANY_MASTER 
        {

            Opening_Cash = Convert.ToDecimal(EOCash.Text),
            Available_Cash = Convert.ToDecimal(EACash.Text)
        };

       var checker = await _connection.UpdateAsync(expense); //here expense.companyid = 0
       ...
```

when you create a new object id is asigned with 0 value, for update id must exist in your table.